# Tabula- Last line from each page not getting extracted using python

Tags: python, tabular, tabula-py

I have a pdf with 4 pages containing 98 rows of tabular data. However when  use tabula, last line from each page is getting excluded in the final output. Below is the code:

```
import tabula
tabula.convert_into('Path/abc.pdf', 'Path/abc.csv', output_format='csv', pages='all',lattice=True)
```

Can somebody suggest any fix ?

I have a pdf with 4 pages containing 98 rows of tabular data. However when  use tabula, last line from each page is getting excluded in the final output. Below is the code:

```
import tabula
tabula.convert_into('Path/abc.pdf', 'Path/abc.csv', output_format='csv', pages='all',lattice=True)
```